# GDI+ Image EXTREMELY faster than C# Image

Tags: c#, c++, .net, gdi+, benchmarking

I decided to benchmark reading an image in C#, and in C++, to decide which language to use in a project i'm thinking about making for myself.
I expected the benchmarks to be extremely close with C++ maybe pushing ahead slightly.

The C# code takes about 300ms each run (I ran each test 100 times), where the C++ code takes about 1.5ms.

So is my C# code wrong? Am I benchmarking it badly? Or is it really just this much slower?

Here's the c# code I used:

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

watch.Start();
Image image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
watch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("DEBUG: {0}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

And the C++ code pretty much boiled down to this:

```
QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
Image * img = Image::FromFile(imagePath);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&stop);
delete img;
return (stop.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) * 1000.0 / freq.QuadPart;
```

Regardless of which language, they need to end up in an Image object, as it provides the functionality i'm going to need.

**=======================================================================**

As xanatos pointed out in the comments, the Image.FromFile does do checking.

More specifically, this:

```
num = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipImageForceValidation(new HandleRef(null, zero));
if (num != 0)
{
    SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipDisposeImage(new HandleRef(null, zero));
    throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(num);
}
```

Using Image.FromStream() instead, you can avoid this.

What i'm wondering is, if you do avoid this and try to load an invalid image file it throws an OutOfMemory exception.
And in C++, you don't do checking like this. So how important is this checking? Can anyone give me a situation where it would be bad to avoid this?

Comment: Both do the same thing in the same way. Check inner implementations of methods you use (`Image.FromFile` and `Image::FromFile`). Maybe there's difference. but for your needs as you see `C++` is the best choice (if development time is not more important than performance)

Comment: I hope you run you project in Release mode without the debugger attached (CTRL+F5)

Comment: I would recommend putting a loop inside the stopwatch.Start() and Stop() and then divide the total time by *numIterations*. This is because .NET has first time run overheads that might account for the extremely lopsided timings.

Comment: Mmmh perhaps the GDI+ is lazily loaded in C# and eagerly loaded in C++? And by watching with IlSpy it seems that the Image.FromFile doesn't simply call Image::FromFile but does some checks.

Comment: Any way to bypass those checks to achieve speed close to the c++ code?

Comment: Is your timing method sound? In other words, if you take an ordinary real-life watch and measure the times "independently", does it agree your measurements?

Comment: Adding to what @ananthonline posted, you want to move your loop. If anything, you want to make it so that you only have one stopwatch that you reset rather than creating a new stopwatch every time, because that puts useless pressure on the GC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your benchmark is flawed.  The problem is that you forgot to actually *do* something with the bitmap.  Like paint it.

GDI+ heavily optimizes the loading of an image.  Very similar to the way .NET optimizes loading an assembly.  It does the bare things necessary, it reads the header of the file to retrieve essential properties.  Format, Width, Height, Dpi.  Then it creates a memory-mapped file to create a mapping to the pixel data in the file.  But doesn't actually *read* the pixel data.

Now the difference comes into play.  System.Drawing.Image next actually reads the pixel data.  That causes page faults, the operating system now reads the file and copies the pixel data into RAM.  Highly desirable, if there's anything wrong with the file then you'll get an exception at the FromFile() call instead of some time later, typically when your program draws the image and is buried in framework code you didn't write.  Your bench mark for the C# code times the creation of the mmf *plus* the reading of the pixel data.

The C++ program is always going to have to pay for reading the pixel data too.  But you didn't measure that, you only measured the cost of creating the MMF.

Answer (score -2):

Few Points which I know

There is  a thing called as CLR. If the said c++ framework(It seems Qt) used The system calls which not depends on .net framework, then obviously it will run fast.

Regarding c# => It is possible to load that assembly before you call it in your code. If you do so,then You can find it's fastness in good scale.

If you use windows platform, then MS wont reduce the execution speed of its own language unless otherwise there is some necessity.